# How to insert array value in database table base on first array column names

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am importing data from csv file so I used that code

```
<?php
$path = "Export.csv";
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen($path, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $row++;
        $data_entries[] = $data ;


    }
    fclose($handle);
}
 echo"<pre>";
 print_r($data_entries);
 echo"</pre>";
?>
```

and my array output like that my first array showing column names after that all array showing value so i want to insert value base on first array column names

```
 Array
 (
  [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Type
        [1] => PinCode
        [2] => APN
        [3] => County
    )
  [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Auction
        [1] => 503082537
        [2] => 502-052-002
        [3] => United States of America
    )
  [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Auction
        [1] => 21596378
        [2] => 628-202-038
        [3] => Australia
     )
 )
```

Comment: What is the expected result ?

Comment: i want to run query like that insert into table(Type,PinCode,APN,County)values('Auction',503082537,502-052-002,'United States of America')............insert into table(Type,PinCode,APN,County)values('Auction',21596378
,628-202-038,'Australia')

)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below code :

```
//extract the column names
$fields = array_shift($data_entries);
$values = array();

// Append the values
foreach($data_entries as $value){
   $values[]="('{$value[0]}', '{$value[1]}', '{$value[2]}', '{$value[3]}' )";
}

// Build the SQL
$sql = "INSERT INTO `TABLE_NAME` (" . implode(',' , $fields) . ") values " . implode(',', $values);
```

Comment: i have 60 column in table i have to expand it like that $values[]="('{$value[0]}', '{$value[1]}', '{$value[2]}', '{$value[3]}','{$value[4]}' )"; there is any way dont need to expand  it '{$value[60]}'

Answer (score 0):

You might try a different approach, since your data is coming from a CSV file.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'Export.csv' INTO TABLE YourTable;
```

There are many options, read the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html